# How are views actually created out of multiple SmartParts?

Tags: .net

In the Microsoft Composite UI Application Block ("CAB"), how are views actually created when made up of multiple SmartPart components?

I've read as many blogs as I can find on CAB, but for the most part all I can find are primarily "Introduction To..." articles that go over basic concepts and tutorials that implement very primitive principles of the framework. I cannot seem to find any good, but easy to understand examples that create 1 screen out of multiple smart parts though.

A short list of some of the stuff I've found very helpful getting started, but lacking the depth I now require;

- http://richnewman.wordpress.com/about/code-listings-and-diagrams/intro-to-cab-toc/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17488/A-Composite-UI-Application-Block-CAB-MDI-applicati
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2007/10/29/composite-application-block-cab-programming-essentials-crucial-for-cab-performance.aspx

I hope this isn't considered too broad for an SO question, but if anyone can possibly explain or at least point me in the right direction that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to start with modern composite application framework [PRISM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) (by MS).

There are source files with examples and good free books with explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, my employer's software is already well established using CAB. Trying to get a better understanding of it after some team re-structuring.